# Straight quotes in math equation?

Tags: math-mode

How can I put straight quotes inside a math equation?

I would like to use straight quotes to surround a string-like piece of data that is displayed using `\mathtt`. Single or double quotes are both acceptable to me.

This code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

$fn(\mathtt{"a"})$

\end{document}
```

will generate curly quotes.

Comment: What does your preamble looks like? What packages do you use, that a relevant to the question? In other words: [could you provide a minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/34551)?

Comment: A provided a minimal example, but I wonder if it really makes a difference in this case. Using [codecogs with just the equation](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?fn%28\mathtt{%22a%22}%29) I get the same result.

Comment: I would use `\texttt` instead of `\mathtt`, i.e., I'd write `$fn(\texttt{"a"})$`.

Comment: @gioele : Sorry, I thought that `babel`, for instance, could interfere, but it's not the case.

Comment: @Mico, `\texttt` looks indeed the easiest solution. But is it correct/idiomatic to use `\text*` formatting inside the math environment? Could you post that as a separate answer?

Comment: Since @egreg has already mentioned the possibility of using `\texttt` toward the end of his answer, I think I should hold off on posting a separate answer that mentions `\texttt`. As far I can tell, `\texttt` and `\mathtt` are equally correct/idiomatic; it's just that `\texttt` provides an easier method for achieving your objective.

Comment: @Clément definitely Babel will interfere if an attempt is made to make `"` math active at the same time it is a Babel shorthand (case of german language). However, changing the mathcode of `"` to something else than `"8000` would not interfere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `"` in mathematical formulas, it makes sense to define it so that it always produces straight quotes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathdblquotechar}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`"}

\newcommand{\mathdblquote}{\mathtt{\mathdblquotechar}}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`"\lowercase{\endgroup
  \let~\mathdblquote
}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`"="8000 }

\begin{document}

$\mathit{fn}(\mathtt{"a"})$

$\mathit{fn}(\texttt{"a"})$

And $"a"$

\end{document}
```

Of course, `\texttt{"a"}` would be easier.

[image]

For single quotes, the simplest strategy is to define a new symbol font and use the TS1 encoded font. However I'd use the backquote in order not to override the usage of `'` in math.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{textcomp}

\DeclareSymbolFont{textcomp}{TS1}{\ttdefault}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{`}{\mathord}{textcomp}{39}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathdblquotechar}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`"}

\newcommand{\mathdblquote}{\mathtt{\mathdblquotechar}}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`"\lowercase{\endgroup
  \let~\mathdblquote
}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`"="8000 }

\begin{document}

$\mathit{fn}(\mathtt{"a"})$ and $\mathit{fn}(\mathtt{`a`})$

$\mathit{fn}(\texttt{"a"})$ and $\mathit{fn}(\texttt{'a'})$

And $"a"$ and $`a`$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\texttt` would do the wrong thing.

Comment: I propose you try with `\usepackage[german]{babel}` ... I deny all responsability to what will happen with your computer...

Comment: @jfbu Happily I'm not using German. `;-)`

Comment: as in its Sturm und Drang exaggeration `mathastext` thought some of its users would, it had to go through quite some complexities to handle such interactions with Babel shorthands one wish to have mathematically active...

Comment: @jfbu In that case, probably directly using `\mathdblquote` is the simplest choice.

Comment: I think so, too.

Comment: Can we apply this also for a single quote?

Comment: @alper I added a solution

Answer (score 3):

You could declare the quote to be a variable like the chars, but this will have side effects if you use them outside \mathXX-fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareMathSymbol{"}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`"}
\begin{document}

$"a" \quad \mathtt{"a"}$

\end{document}
```

[image]